# jquery trigger action on focus or click but not both

Tags: jquery, focus, click

I have this sample code:

```
$myTrigger
    .click(function(e){
         alert('click');
    })
    .focus(function(e){
         alert('focus');
         $(this).click()
    })
```

The intent is that I want something to happen when you click on $myTrigger. If, on the other hand, you tab onto it via the keyboard (ie, focus) I want the exact same thing to happen, so I ask it to click.

The catch is if I click on it, it also focuses. So both alerts are going off.

Is there a way to prevent the focus event from going off when clicking?

UPDATE:

Ajm's comment got me thinking that I'm maybe asking the wrong thing.

Question: Does a click event always also trigger focus in javascript (and/or in jQuery?). Can I assume whenever I want to handle both clicking with the mouse and tabbing-in with the keyboard, the focus() event will handle both?

Or is it dependent on the particular element that I'm attaching the events to? (In this case $myObject happens to be an anchor tag (link).

Comment: Why not just get rid of the click function and only keep focus? If every click is also focus and you want it to work on both click and focus, only use focus.

Comment: Would it make more sense to make the action an external function that both click and focus call? That would kind of skip this problem entirely. >> Ignore this per the comment below.

Comment: @ajm It will still run that function twice because when you click the focus also happens

Comment: @Adam: That'd work if I knew for SURE that this was standard browser behavior. Is it? @ajm: that wouldn't solve it...the function would just be called twice.

Comment: Sorry guys, was thinking in terms of one function calling another. A focus would indeed presuppose either a click on the element or something like a tab to it, depending on the type of element you're working with. What kind of element(s) are in $myTrigger?

Comment: @ajm...good questions. I've updated my post to maybe ask the better questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery has a built-in functon for this that's not used all that often called [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$mytrigger.one('click focus', function() { alert("event"); });
```

This will only trigger once, or you can re-bind if you want afterwards.

Comment: Does that call 'one of these two events once' or does it call 'each of these events once'? The documentation doesn't say. (Obviously, I can try it out an will as soon as I can...)

Comment: In the documentation , it says the in case of multiple events, .one will be called once for each event type.

Answer (score 6):

To trigger click() for TAB focus (and prevent click() from being triggered twice when focus comes from a mouse click), I did the following:

```
$('#item').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).data("mouseDown", true);
});

$('#item').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeData("mouseDown");
});

$('#item').focus(function(){
    if (!$(this).data("mouseDown"))
        $(this).click();
});
```

Does that work good for you?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
$myTrigger
    .mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // don't grab focus
    })
    .click(function(e) {
         alert('click');
    })
    .focus(function(e) {
         alert('focus');
         $(this).click()
    });
```

This will leave the keyboard focus wherever it was before when clicking the button, while still allowing the button to become focused via Tab (or programmatically calling `.focus()` on it).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a while back.  I ***[solved it](http://www.brunellweb.com/index.php/2009/08/15/escape-clickdouble-click-hell-in-ie8-and-firefox-with-jquery/)*** by responding to the first event, and ignoring events for the next 20ms.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(OnReady);

var okToClick = true;

function OnReady() {
    //Attach to both click and focus events
    $("#item").click(PerformAction).focus(PerformAction);
}

function PerformAction() {
    if (okToClick) {
        okToClick = false;

        // Do something interesting here...

        setTimeout(function() { okToClick = true; }, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that is so much a solution as it is an ugly hack around the issue.

Comment: Yep.  It's a hack.  Can't argue there.  But in my case, it was the *only* solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only the **focus()** method and read this article about events (e) types on JavaScript: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

To detect what event you got with you mouse or keyboard (to test it), u can use:

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
alert(e.type);
```

Comment: I suppose my question is really "does focus ALWAYS get called on CLICK?"

Comment: @DA - Yeah, because when you click on the element you're activating it's focus too since your focused in that element. :)

Comment: well, I did a test and that does not appear to be the case. You can't give a DIV a focus event, for instance, and then click on it and have that event fired. It appears that this is only true for 'focusable' elements.

Comment: You are true. But every elements can become "focusable" in HTML5 : you just have to add a "tabindex" property to you element. As seen in the W3C ARIA draft : http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/ . (I know it's old topic but Google sent me here in 2013!)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent focus from being called twice set a variable to tell if the element has focus.

```
var hasFocus = false;
$('#myTrigger').focusIn(
   function(){
      hasFocus = true;
      //do stuff
   }
);

$('#myTrigger').focusOut(
   function(){
      hasFocus = false;
   }
);
```

Put all functionality on focus and tell jQuery to set the foucus on the element when it is clicked if you run into a browser which doesn't do that.

```
$(#myTrigger).click( function(){ if(!hasFocus){$(#myTrigger).focus()}});
```

Comment: Good point. You'll have to set a variable to see if it's gotten focus yet.