# Prevent focus on button click in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, focus, onclick

I am facing more or less the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458109/jquery-prevent-focus-on-click), (i.e. I have a submit input which is clicked programmatically when it gains focus after a tab, but the focus handler is also invoked when the user clicks on the button, causing a double submit). The solution suggested in the linked post works, but I need one which does not require jQuery. Does anyone have some thoughts on that? Please note that I need the button's click behavior to remain the same, as it is binded to an asp .net server-side event. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to prevent the form from submitting so add an event listener and then code how you want JavaScript to handle submitting the form. Also +1 to your question for asking how to competently code this without depending on any frameworks! :-)

Some rough code to give you an idea of how to prevent a form from submitting...

```
if (window.addEventListener)
{
 forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(e) {e.preventDefault(); eval(id_forms[e.target.id]+'();');},false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent)
{
 forms[i].attachEvent('onsubmit',function(e,f) {e.returnValue=false; eval(id_forms[e.srcElement.id]+'();');});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution looks good (perhaps minus the use of eval :) ). I have implemented another approach that I forgot to write down here, so I will do that, but give the answer to you.

Comment: I use eval sparingly, this code is actually part of how I prevent forms from submitting on my site so I can have JavaScript handle them instead. I still process forms submitted when JavaScript is disabled and determine the difference by appending ?ajax=1 when JavaScript is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with having a keyUp and keyDown handler in which I set/unset a isKeyPressed variable. It is my understanding that the sequence of events that happens when tabbing is the following:

- keyDown
- focus gained
- keyUp

Thus, in the focus event handler I check if the focus was gained by tabbing (i.e. if the isKeyPressed is set to true) and submit the form there. Otherwise, if the focus was gained after a click(), the isKeyPressed will not be set to true, and I will not trigger the form submission programatically.

Comment: Events are DOM based, not from JavaScript, there is a good list available here of all places: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events