# How to run a function only once when it's triggered by both focus and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an input element with 2 events attached: focus and click. They both fire off the same helper function.

When I tab to the input, the focus event fires and my helper is run once. No problems there.

When the element already has focus, and I click on it again, the click event fires and my  helper runs once. No problems there either.

But when the element does not have focus, and I click on it, BOTH events fire, and my helper is run TWICE. How can I keep this helper only running once?

I saw a couple similar questions on here, but didn't really follow their answers. I also discovered the .live jQuery handler, which seems like it could work if I had it watch a status class. But seems like there should be a simpler way. The .one handler would work, except I need this to work more than once.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best answer here would be to come up with a design that isn't trying to trigger the same action on two different events that can both occur on the same user action, but since you haven't really explained the overall problem you're coding, we can't really help you with that approach.

One approach is to keep a single event from triggering the same thing twice is to "debounce" the function call and only call the function from a given element if it hasn't been called very recently (e.g. probably from the same user event).  You can do this by recording the time of the last firing for this element and only call the function if the time has been longer than some value.

Here's one way you could do that:

```
function debounceMyFunction() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var prevTime = $(this).data("prevActionTime");
    $(this).data("prevActionTime", now);
    // only call my function if we haven't just called it (within the last second)
    if (!prevTime || now - prevTime > 1000) {
        callMyFunction();
    }
}

$(elem).focus(debounceMyFunction).click(debounceMyFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I thought about checking the time as well but was hoping there's a way that's more elegant. Thanks much for the code sample though!

Comment: @dylanized - there isn't any way that I'm aware of to know that a given click also just triggered focus (as part of the same event sequence) without looking at timing.

Comment: @jfriend00 - focus is always called first. The reason focus is always first is that it will fire onmousedown however click is going to require both mousedown and mouseup to occur.

Comment: @TravisJ - but knowing that focus is always called first doesn't help solve the issue because in the OP's case, sometimes focus isn't called at all (if the element already has focus).  The OP needs to know when they get a click if the focus event was just generated.  My suggestion is to use timing to know that because I'm not aware of any other way to know it.  A simple flag set on focus can't be used all by itself because a focus event (say from tabbing to the field) followed some time later by a click event needs to process both events.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a timeout which get's cleared and set. This would introduce a slight delay but ensures only the last event is triggered.

```
$(function() {
  $('#field').on('click focus', function() {
    debounce(function() {
        // Your code goes here.
        console.log('event');
    });
  });  
});

var debounceTimeout;

function debounce(callback) {
  clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
  debounceTimeout = setTimeout(callback, 500);
}
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/APEdu/

**UPDATE**

To address a comment elsewhere about use of a global, you could make the `doubleBounceTimeout` a collection of timeouts with a key passed in the event handler. Or you could pass the same timeout to any methods handling the same event. This way you could use the same method to handle this for any number of inputs.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjmemay/zN8Ns/1/

```
$('.button').on('mousedown', function(){
    $(this).data("mouseDown", true);
});

$('.button').on('mouseup', function(){
    $(this).removeData("mouseDown");
});

$('.button').on('focus', function(){
    if (!$(this).data("mouseDown"))
        $(this).trigger('click.click');
});

$(".button").on('click.click',evHandler);
```

Which I stole directly from this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9440580/264498

Comment: Nice solution. I'm assuming this works because the we queue the mousedown before the focus? i.e. if we put the focus before the mousedown, if would not work?

Comment: @dylanized I think it works because mousedown fires before focus does, when clicking. mousedown, focus, mouseup. So when the event is a focus, it checks to see if the mousedown flag is set on the element.

Tabbing, and spacebar don't really come into play here. That is to say, I don't think the order the events are registered in the code is important, just the order that they fire.

Comment: The only caveat I found is if you mousedown on the input, and then move off, it doesn't clear the flag, breaking focus events. I tried to address this issue here, but this may or may not be relevant to you depending on the structure of your document, your js, and what its being used for:
http://jsfiddle.net/cjmemay/zN8Ns/2/

Comment: Discovered another edge case where this approach has a problem: labels. If you click on a label that is associated with an input, it sends the focus to the input, but none of the mouse events register. So the evHandler is executed twice. A solution would be to watch the label's mousedowns/clicks as well, but probably simpler at that point to go with the debounce approach...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you don't actually need the click handler. It sounds like this event is attached to an element which when clicked gains focus and fires the focus handler. So clicking it is always going to fire your focus handler, so you only need the focus handler.

If this is not the case then unfortunately no, there is no easy way to achieve what you are asking. Adding/removing a class on focus and only firing the click when the class isn't present is about the only way I can think of.

I have it - 2 options

1 - bind the click handler to the element in the focus callback

2 - bind the focus and the click handler to a different class, and use the focus callback to add the click class and use blur to remove the click class

Comment: Thanks for answering. I need the click handler for the scenario when the input ALREADY has focus, but gets clicked a second / third / fourth time.

Comment: @LiamBailey that doesn't do anything because it gains focus before firing the click function. The if statement is pointless.

Comment: What about those 2 options then>

Answer (score 1):

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ImOXUFAm/2/edit)**

I'm just simply setting a flag to gate off the click when the element is clicked the first time (focus given). Then, if the element gets focus from tabbing, the flag is also removed so that the first click will work.

```
var $foo = $('#foo');

var flag = 0;
$foo.click(function() {
  if (flag) {
    flag = 0;
    return false;
  }
  console.log('clicked');
});

$foo.focus(function() {
  flag = 1;
  console.log('focused');
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 9) {
    var $focused = $('input:focus');
    if ($focused.is($foo)) {
      flag = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Several ways this doesn't work.  If focus is set some other way besides the Tab key or click (such as auto-focus, programmatic focus, etc...) or if all keys aren't allowed to propagate up to the document.  Also, this implementation is not very extensible to use in multiple places as it uses a global flag.

Comment: @jfriend00 you know the global flag isn't necessary, but good point about the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great discussion everybody. Seems like the debouncing solution from @jfriend00, and the mousedown solution from Chris Meyers, are both decent ways to handle it.

I thought some more, and also came up with this solution:

```
// add focus event
$myInput.focus(function() {
    myHelper();
    // while focus is active, add click event
    setTimeout(function() {
        $myInput.click(function() {
            myHelper(); 
        });
    }, 500);    // slight delay seems to be required
});

// when we lose focus, unbind click event
$myInput.blur(function() {
    $myInput.off('click');
});
```

But seems like those others are slightly more elegant. I especially like Chris' because it doesn't involve dealing with the timing.

Thanks again!!

Comment: If you are going to use a timeout anyway, why not use my approach? Doesn't require bind and unbind.

Comment: I agree that your approach is cleaner. Just added this cuz it seemed like a viable option. Think I'm gonna try the mousedown approach, but will use yours if that doesn't work out!!

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @Christopher Meyers solution.

Some intro: Before the click event fires, 2 events are preceding it, mousedown & mouseup, if the mousedown is fired, we know that probably the mouseup will fire.
Therefore we probably wouldn't like that the focus event handler would execute its action. One scenario in which the mouseup wouldn't fire is if the user starts clicking the button then drags the cursor away, for that we use the blur event.

```
  let mousedown = false;

  const onMousedown = () => {
    mousedown = true;
  };

  const onMouseup = () => {
    mousedown = false;
    // perform action
  };

  const onFocus = () => {
    if (mousedown) return;
    // perform action
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    mousedown = false;
    // perform action if wanted
  };
```

The following events would be attached:

```
const events = [
    { type: 'focus', handler: onFocus },
    { type: 'blur', handler: onBlur },
    { type: 'mousedown', handler: onMousedown },
    { type: 'mouseup', handler: onMouseup }
];
```